# What does LNK2019 actually mean? Blackjack project error

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, lnk2019, blackjack

I have been programming in c++ for about six months now. Just recently i started to make a blackjack simulator in QT creator, which means i am very new to the QT environment. I have created a few classes i thought was needed etc. Everything works out fine until i try to create a class object in my mainWindow.h!

So the problem pops up when im trying to create a Deals object. I also create a new Deals(); in the .cpp file ofc.

The error message i get is called LNK2019. I have been googling around for a while to understand what it actually means and how i can understand the error statements.

In this specific case the errorcode looks like this:

`mainblackjackmainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Deals::Deals(void)" (??0Deals@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainBlackJackMainWindow::MainBlackJackMainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainBlackJackMainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)`

how should i read this to be able to understand it?
And if u have any ideas or tips on how to solve this i would be glad.

Best regards J

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: Did u link all files in project?

Comment: Did you implement Deals::Deals()?

Comment: Yes Deals::Deals(); is implemented

Comment: Then I would check to make sure that the cpp file that implements Deals::Deals() is in your project and it is being built.